# How can you terminate a string after k consecutive numbers have been found?

Tags: python, string, optimization

Say I have some list with files of the form `*.1243.*`, and I wish to obtain everything before these 4 digits. How do I do this efficiently?

An ugly, inefficient example of working code is:

```
names = []
for file in file_list:
    words = file.split('.')
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        if word.isdigit():
            if int(word)>999 and int(word)<10000:
                names.append(' '.join(words[:i]))
                break
print(names)
```

Obviously though, this is far from ideal and I was wondering about better ways to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use regular expressions for this.

```
import re

name = []
for file in file_list:
    m = re.match(r'^(.+?)\.\d{4}\.', file)
    if m:
        name.append(m.groups()[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression, this would become simpler

```
import re

names = ['hello.1235.sas','test.5678.hai']

for fn in names:
    myreg = r'(.*)\.(?:\d{4})\..*'
    output = re.findall(myreg,fn)
    print(output)
```

output:

```
['hello']
['test']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that all entries has the same format, here is list comprehension approach:

```
[item[0] for item in filter(lambda start, digit, end: len(digit) == 4, (item.split('.') for item in file_list))]
```

To be fair I also like solution, provided by @James. Note, that downside of this list comprehension is three loops:
 1. On all items to split
 2. Filtering all items, that match
 3. Returning result.

With regular for loop it could be be more sufficient:

```
output = []
for item in file_list:
    begging, digits, end = item.split('.')
    if len(digits) == 4:
        output.append(begging)
```

It does only one loop, which way better.

Comment: The * in this example could be anything, including "How.Are.You?.1423.hi.txt". The forced split wouldn't work in this case. I didn't understand James' regular expression string code (never seen them before so working off documentation) so I'm now trying to rewrite newbie's example to generator format.

Comment: @Mitchell Faas, oh, I see. Then, I would say your approach is correct. At least it makes least possible iterations and readable enough (at least from what I see so far). Jameses expression supposed to get  everything before it will find a group of four digits, separated by dots

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Positive Lookahead (?=(\.\d{4}))`

```
import re
pattern=r'(.*)(?=(\.\d{4}))'

text=['*hello.1243.*','*.1243.*','hello.1235.sas','test.5678.hai','a.9999']


print(list(map(lambda x:re.search(pattern,x).group(0),text)))
```

output:

```
['*hello', '*', 'hello', 'test', 'a']
```